# Localization of menu items

Tags: localization, l10n

In `register_nav_menu()` function is possible to pass the second parameter inside wp l10n function:

`register_nav_menu( 'primary', __( 'Primary Menu', 'theme-slug' ) );`

but how to localize the menu items?

Answer (score 0):

Get a WPML plugin - https://wpml.org/

Seriously, get it - it's the most complete solution for multilingual WP site. You can write your own code to translate menu items, but it is not worth it.